# Using interfaces in generic interfaces

Tags: generics, interface, typescript

I use generics when using object literals to help simplify the process of interface building.  So, for example, my base interface for all objects that use string as keys is

```
interface IStringTMap<T> { [s: string]: T; };
```

If I wanted to use this to enforce an object to be entirely made of functions I'd make a new interface

```
interface IStringFunctionMap extends IStringTMap<Function> { };
```

Occasionally, however, I want to use more complex objects.  For example, let's say I wanted to build the following structure:

```
var obj = {
    "group_1" : {
        "func_1" : function() {},
        "func_2" : function() {}
    },
    "group_2" : {
        "func_1" : function() {},
        "func_2" : function() {}
    }
}
```

I can build this interface pretty easily from raw bits

```
interface IFunctionGroups { [s: string]: { [s: string]: Function } };
```

**How would I go about making this more readable using my existing `IStringTMap` interface?**

I've tried using my caveman logic, but just shoving one interface into another

```
interface IFunctionGroups extends IStringTMap<IStringFunctionMap>;
```

Gives me the following error:

> An interface an only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding curly braces `{ }` after your interface declaration corrects the problem:

```
interface IStringTMap<T> { [s: string]: T; }

interface IStringFunctionMap extends IStringTMap<Function> { }

interface IFunctionGroups extends IStringTMap<IStringFunctionMap> { }

var obj: IFunctionGroups = {
    "group_1" : {
        "func_1" : function() {},
        "func_2" : function() {}
    },
    "group_2" : {
        "func_1" : function() {},
        "func_2" : function() {}
    }
}
```

This compiles without errors or warnings to:

```
var obj = {
    "group_1": {
        "func_1": function () { },
        "func_2": function () { }
    },
    "group_2": {
        "func_1": function () { },
        "func_2": function () { }
    }
};
```

Comment: Went back and checked my code.  I had left the brackets out after the interface declaration - derp.  Either way, your code gave me the side-by side that highlighted the omission.  Thanks!  Have a check and +1.

Comment: Question: If I modified my question to remove the brackets after `interface IFunctionGroups extends IStringTMap<IStringFunctionMap> { };` would you be willing to edit your question to point out that they're missing?  Might as well try to make the question relevant and useful.